# Replacements/Substitutions in Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am a new user of Mathematica and have some questions about the simplifications of calculated expressions. 
I am unable to attach an image of the session, but my Mathematica commands are:

```
Element[{x,y,z},Reals] 
Element[{x0,y0,z0},Reals]
rhatV={x-x0,y-y0,z-z0}
rhat=Norm[rhatV]
```

In the expression for rhat, I am unable to get rid of the `Abs` functions, despite the Reals declarations.

```
phi=1/rhat
D[phi,x]
```

In the evaluated derivative is there a way to have x-x0 in the numerator recognized as rhatV[[1]] and the denominator as rhat^3, such that it can be used in additional operations?

Comment: Look up `Assuming[]`...

Comment: The documentation included with _Mathematica_ includes two tutorials you should read: _Using Assumptions_ and _Simplifying with Assumptions_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formulation of the assumptions are one problem, and the fact that you're not *using* them is another:

```
$Assumptions = {Element[{x, y, z}, Reals],
   Element[{x0, y0, z0}, Reals]
   };

rhatV = {x - x0, y - y0, z - z0};

rhat = Simplify[Norm[rhatV]];

phi = 1/rhat;

D[phi, x]
```

> $-\frac{x-\text{x0}}{\left((x-\text{x0})^2+(y-\text{y0
>    })^2+(z-\text{z0})^2\right)^{3/2}}$

Here I put the assumptions in a special variable `$Assumptions`, assuming (no pun intended) that you'll want to re-use them in further calculations. But to use them in the first place, you have to add `Simplify` or another command that specifically utilizes the `Assumptions` option.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that the declaration of the variables as Reals would be automatically incorporated in subsequent calculations, but I understand from your response that it should be formulated as Assumptions and have calculations specifically invoke the Assumptions. I hope there is a way to have substitutions made so that the numerator is recognized as the first element of the vector rhatV and the denominator as rhat^3.

Comment: @user1031565 For the last part of the question, you may be better off using [spherical coordinates](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14362/245).

Answer (score 9):

`Mathematica` is a term rewriting system, variables need not to be declared as in compiled languages. For a general view I recommend reading this [post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/how-to-specify-mathematica-as-a-programming-language/272#272) by Leonid Shifrin. In general, symbolic variables are processed as complex if not assumed otherwise. To specify assumptions there are a few ways :

- `$Assumptions` are recommended when you want to use global assumptions.
- for local assumptions there is `Assuming[ assum, expr]` where `expr` can be a compound expression (see [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html), a shorthand - `;`) :

> ```
> Assuming[ assum, expr]    evaluates expr with assum appended to $Assumptions, so that assum
> is included in the default assumptions used by functions such as Refine, Simplify, and
> Integrate
> ```

Many functions as `Simplify`, `Refine`, and `Integrate` have options `Assumptions` that specifies default assumptions to be made about symbolic quantities.

Here are a few examples how to specify desired assumptions and compute a given expression :

```
D[ Simplify[ 1/ Norm @ rhatV, {x, y, z}  ∈ Reals && {x0, y0, z0}  ∈ Reals], x]
```

and

```
D[ Simplify[ 1/EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, {x0, y0, z0}], 
             {x, y, z}  ∈ Reals && {x0, y0, z0}  ∈ Reals], x]
```

and

```
Assuming[ {x, y, z}  ∈ Reals && {x0, y0, z0}  ∈ Reals, D[ 1/Simplify @ Norm @ rhatV, x] ]
```

all these expressions return :

[image]

Comment: Thanks to you and @Jens for clearing up my confusion on declarations.