# How to write a differential operator in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction, operators

I have a very basic question.  I am trying to code the LHS of the differential equation: 
$$\Big[\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}\big(\sin\theta\frac{d}{d\theta}\big)-\frac{m^2}{\sin^2\theta}+n(n+1)\Big]f(\theta)=0$$
into *Mathematica*.  As you can see, in the first term, the differential operator is nested and is to properly act on the function $f(\theta)$.

I tried to use `#1`, but (lol) I don't know how to use it!

This is what I have:

```
Sin[θ]^(-1) D[Sin[θ] D[#1, θ], θ] - m^2*#1/Sin[θ]^2 + n (n + 1) #1
```

What next?!

**Also**:  I don't want to just stick in `f[θ]` into where I have `#1`, because eventually I would like to be able to make change of variables!

Comment: Aren't you just missing an `&` at the end?

Comment: One way to go about this is discussed in a notebook available [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/325/). See the first example in the section "Some noncommutative algebraic manipulation"

Comment: @Ajasja Hey! it looks like this is on the right track.  I added an `&` at the end, and all the `#1`'s turned Green.  What next?

Comment: You might also be interested in this: [Having the derivative be an operator](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5032/245) and [How to change coordinates of a differential operator?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14362/245)

Comment: @Jens Thank you for these reference!  They are very helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just define a `Function` ?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[m, n, x, foo]
oper = Function[{f, \[Theta]}, (1/
      Sin[\[Theta]] D[Sin[\[Theta]] D[f[\[Theta]], \[Theta]]] - 
     m^2/Sin[\[Theta]]^2 f[\[Theta]] + n (n + 1) f[\[Theta]])];
oper[foo, x]
foo[x_] := Sin[x]*Cos[x]*x^4
oper[foo, x]
```

Comment: (+1) That's how I'd do it.

Comment: **Except** - you don't need the `theta` in the argument list. In fact, this mixes two alternative approaches: either make the operator always differentiate its argument `f` with respect to the global variable `theta`, or do the differentiation with respect to the first slot in `f`. It's two different things.

Comment: +1, that's the obvious way. but you've mixed up $\theta$ and `#1` :)

Comment: @Nasser sorry I didn't have time to respond yesterday. I added my own answer to explain what I'd do differently.

Answer (score 8):

Well, I hope you're not pulling my leg here (at 1000 rep one would think you have met [pure  (anonymous) functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) before, or have at least learned where to get help: type `&` and press `F1`). But here it goes:

```
(*Assign the operator in the form of an anonymous function  to oper*)
oper = Sin[\[Theta]]^(-1) D[Sin[\[Theta]] D[#1, \[Theta]], \[Theta]] - 
   m^2*#1/Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + n (n + 1) #1 &;

(*use it*)
oper [f[\[Theta]]]
```

Comment: Lol!  I am not pulling your leg.  My 1000 reputation is coming from asking 1000 idiotic questions.  Check my profile.  But your response is very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

The differential operator in this question is itself indexed by two variables `m` and `n`. This arises after expressing the Laplace operator in spherical coordinates (see the answer by b.gatessucks, but that answer was incomplete because it dropped the $\phi$ dependence too early) and then assuming that the function on which we operate is proportional to $\exp(im\phi)$.

In the other answers that define a function for this operator, the parameters `m` and `n` appear as **global variables** inside the function. That's inconvenient in practice because these indices correspond to physical parameters (the angular momentum components) that are adjustable. So `m` and `n` need to appear in the list of variables on which the operator depends.

The next thing on which the operator depends is the independent variable $\theta$ with respect to which we want to take derivatives. It would be reasonable to make this work along the lines of `D`, which means in particular that it should handle a case like this:

```
foo[x_] := Sin[θ] Sin[x]
D[foo[θ], θ]
```

> `2 Sin[θ] Cos[θ]`

This will *not work* if you define an operator function like this:

```
myOp = Function[{f, θ}, D[f[θ], θ]];
myOp[foo[θ], θ]
```

> $\sin ^2(\theta )'(\theta )+(2 \sin (\theta )\cos (\theta ))(\theta )$

The problem is that `myOp` expects to be passed a function instead of an expression. This is not how `D` works. The purpose of the second argument of `D[f,x]` is to identify the variable *appearing in* `f` that is to be varied. The above method in `myOp` is basically what Nasser used in his answer. It performs a differentiation with respect to the first slot in the first argument assuming it is a function, and then return the result with the variable $\theta$ inserted in that slot. That's not wrong, it's just an interpretation of differentiation that differs from what `D` does.

An approach more consistent with `D` is this definition:

```
newOp = Function[{f, θ}, D[f, θ]];
newOp[foo[θ], θ]
```

> `2 Cos[θ] Sin[θ]`

But in this question, the variable `θ` plays a role that is better grouped together with the indices `m` and `n`, and separated from the function `f` on which the operator acts.  Now that I identified how I want to think about the variables on which the differential operator depends, the definition I would use is as follows:

```
Clear[operNM, n, m, var]
operNM[n_, m_, var_] = Function[{f}, D[Sin[var] D[f, var], var]/Sin[var] - 
    (m^2 f)/Sin[var]^2 + n (n + 1) f
  ];
```

This defines `operNM[n, m, var]` as an operator to which you then supply an expression that it operates on:

```
operNM[n,m,θ][foo[θ]]
```

> $\csc (\theta ) \left(4 \sin (\theta ) \cos^2(\theta )-2 \sin ^3(\theta )\right)-m^2+n(n+1) \sin ^2(\theta )$

Having the operator act on expressions instead of expecting its argument to be a function is more practical especially when you deal with functions of several variables. In quantum mechanics, the name of the coordinate in a many-particle wave function is tied to the index of the particle it represents, and function slots are then not a convenient way to keep track of that information. In `operNM` you can choose the desired differentiation variable independently of where in the expression it appears.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on version 9 you could use the built-in functions (previously available in the `VectorAnalysis` package). The following might get you close to what you need :

```
Laplacian[f[theta], {r, theta, phi}, "Spherical"] // Simplify
(* (Cot[theta] Derivative[1][f][theta] + (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[theta])/r^2 *)
```