# How can I make Mathematica compute an operator?

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction, syntax

I would like Mathematica to write down the Laplace-Beltrami operator in $R^N$ 
$$
 \Delta f = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2} + \frac{N-1}{r} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \delta f,
$$
$$
\delta  = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{N - 1} {\frac{1}
{{q_j \left( {\sin \theta _j } \right)^{N - j - 1} }}\frac{\partial }
{{\partial \theta _j }}\left( {\left( {\sin \theta _j } \right)^{N - j - 1} \frac{\partial }
{{\partial \theta _j }}} \right)} ,
$$
$$
\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {q_1  = 1,} & {q_j  = \left( {\sin \theta _1 \sin \theta _2  \cdots \sin \theta _{j - 1} } \right)^2 ,} & {j = 2, \ldots ,N - 1}  \\
 \end{array}
$$
as a function of $N$, i.e. I want to specify $N$ and compute the symbolic sum of $\delta$.
I tried with

```
q[1] := 1

q[j_] := (Product[Sin[Subscript[θ, i]], {i, 1, j - 1}])^2

δ[N_] := 
 Sum[1/(q[j] (Sin[Subscript[θ, j]])^(N - j - 1)) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), 
SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(j\)]]\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\((Sin[
\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(j\)]])\), \(N - j - 1\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), 
SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(j\)]])\)\), {j, 1, N - 1} ]
```

but it does not work:

> Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed.

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post code as LaTeX.  Post it in a way that it can be copied and pasted back to Mathematica.

Comment: Note that you cannot use `N`, it's a built-in.

Comment: Also, see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15605/how-to-define-a-differential-operator), and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20519/how-to-write-a-differential-operator-in-mathematica?rq=1).

Comment: I will recommend checking prior MSE posts related to this topic. Among other things, `Product` is not going to be useful because it assumes commuting factors.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

The partial derivatives are causing the problems in your above code. If you realy just want to write it down here is a version that just prints the definition:

```
\[Delta][N_] :=
Sum[Row[{1/(q[j] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], j]]^(N - j - 1)), (
"\[PartialD]")/Subscript["\[PartialD]\[Theta]", j], "(", 
Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], j]]^(N - j - 1), ("\[PartialD]")/
Subscript["\[PartialD]\[Theta]", j], ")"}], {j, 1, N - 1} ]
```

This will create a sum of terms which can not be manipulated algebraically by mathematica since they are row expressions.

Comment: Thank you Steil, that was what I was looking for.