# Writing (differential) operators

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to apply the differential operator

$- (\partial_\theta -\frac{i}{\sin (\theta)} \partial_\phi + s \cot (\theta))$

to a function $F$ (Spherical Harmonics), which is dependent on $\theta$ and $\phi$ like `SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ]`. How do I write this differential operator in Mathematica? The implementation should not depend on the particular function.

A non-working attempt I made is

```
 (-Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0] + I/Sin[θ] Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1] + s Cot[θ]) 
   SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ]
```

But Mathematica didn't resolve the derivatives as stated in [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html). Is there an easy solution to this, that works like multiplication from the left?

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5434/using-d-to-find-a-symbolic-derivative/5441) seems to solve this by repeating `f` after every differential. Is this really necessary? Mathematically, differential operators should not care about what comes after them, should they?

#### Edit

Just found [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20519) about writing differential operators, but don't really understand it.

Comment: You need to write the operator as a pure function and enclose its argument in square brackets: `(-Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][#] + 
    I/Sin[\[Theta]] Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][#] + s Cot[\[Theta]]) & [
 SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon it appears that you missed 's Cot[\[Theta]] #', which seems to throw a monkey wrench into your solution since  it somehow cant evaluate this. (it outputs (0&) at the end of each result).

Full line: Y[s_, l_, m_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] :=  
  Simplify[(-1)^
      s Sqrt[(l + s)!/(l - s)!] (-Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][#] + 
        I/Sin[\[Theta]] Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][#] + 
        s Cot[\[Theta]] Derivative[0, 0, 0, 0][#]) & [
    SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]], 
   Assumptions -> {-l <= s <= 0, -\[Pi] <= \[Phi] <= \[Pi], 
     0 < \[Theta] < \[Pi]}];

Comment: I did not understand that the `s Cot[\[Theta]]` was supposed to be multiplied by the argument. Just change to `(-Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][#] + 
    I/Sin[\[Theta]] Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][#] + s Cot[\[Theta]] #) &[
 SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]]` There is no `0&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use my `DifferentialOperator` package to do what you want. Install with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "https://github.com/carlwoll/DifferentialOperator/releases/download/0.1/DifferentialOperator-0.0.1.paclet"
]
```

and load with:

```
<<DifferentialOperator`
```

Here's a short animation of the package in action for your question:

[image]

For more details, see my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162590/45431) to the linked [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5030/45431).

Comment: YOur package seems perfect. Is it compatible with mathematica 11.3? i get a red cell markation if i enter L2 = esc pd esc ctrl+- x enter

Comment: Don’t use esc, just use pd without the escapes

Comment: Thanks, but now

op[s_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := -(Subscript[
     DifferentialOperator`Private`operator[
      DifferentialOperator[]], \[Theta]] - 
     I/Sin[\[Theta]] Subscript[
      DifferentialOperator`Private`operator[
       DifferentialOperator[]], \[Phi]] + s Cot[\[Theta]]);

Y[s_, l_, m_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] :=  
 Simplify[(-1)^
   s ((l - s)!/(l + s)!) (op[s, \[Theta], \[Phi]] @
     SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]), 
  Assumptions -> {-l <= s <= 0, -\[Pi] <= \[Phi] <= \[Pi], 
    0 < \[Theta] < \[Pi]}]

Comment: (* A contains vector vectors of length n *)

h[h11_, h22_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  h22 * Y[-2, 2, 2, \[Theta], \[Phi]];
h[A[[All, 2]], A[[All, 3]], 1, 1] 

does throw an error, which can be avoided if phi and theta are replaced by a rule, which seems laborious.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use:

```
opL[f_]:=-(D[f,θ]-(I/Sin[θ])*D[f,φ]+s*Cot[θ]*f)
```

Comment: I prefer a pure function version.

Comment: @Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ I like this version because when the operator is applied to a function it look very similar the way in which I write it.