# Partial derivative operator

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

My problem is the yellow part is the partial derivative operator but i don't know how to put this expression because it has 2 problems
The first problem it has 2 variables which are with respect to r and theta.
The second problem i need to get the second derivative for an operator not just the first derivative for theta, I appreciate any help [image].

Comment: Please check the document of `D` and `Derivative`. As to operators, we have many related posts e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172482/1871 (Don't miss the links therein. )

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Derivative` !

Examplary `D[eps[r, teta] Cos[teta]^2,{{r,teta}]`

```
Derivative[1, 1][Function[{r, teta}, eps[r, teta] Cos[teta]^2] ][r, teta]
```

Comment: Can i ask the use of [1,1] is for what?

Comment: Means first derivative of the first/first derivative of the second variable.

Comment: Sorry for that but the whole answer is vague to me i mean i have the second partial derivative not just first derivative so can you write to me the whole equation in one line  like that D[Function[{r, \[Theta]}, 
   Subscript[\[Epsilon], rr] Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + 
    Subscript[\[Epsilon], \[Theta]\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]]^2 - 
    Subscript[\[Epsilon], r\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]]^2]][r, \[Theta]]

Comment: My answer is examplary, but if you understand the syntax ( see documentation `Derivative`) you might apply it  to all the other  terms in your function.

Comment: I checked the syntax in ( documentation Derivative) and I wrote it like that but it seems not right Do you have any suggestion if the below code is right?

Comment: oper = Function[{f, \[Theta]}, (Sin[\[Theta]]^2*D[f[\[Theta]], r ]*
      D[f[\[Theta]], r] + 
     Cos[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]]*D (1/r D[f[\[Theta]], r] + 1/r^2) - 
     Sin[2 \[Theta]] (1/
        r^2 D[f[\[Theta]], \[Theta]] D[f[\[Theta]], \[Theta]]))];
oper[fooo, \[Theta]]
fooo[\[Theta]_] := 
 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 Subscript[\[Epsilon], rr] + 
  Sin[\[Theta]]^2 Subscript[\[Epsilon], \[Theta]\[Theta]] - 
  Sin[2 \[Theta]] Subscript[\[Epsilon], r\[Theta]]
oper[fooo, \[Theta]]