# How to define momentum operator for use with creation and annihilation operators in quantum mechanics

Tags: differential-equations, operators, quantum-computing

I am having trouble writing the momentum operator in the differential form to complete a piece of code shown here so that I can show a commutator [P,Q] = I .

Here is what I have done so far, and I need a way of defining P, not in matrix form. Whelp.

[image]

Comment: Can [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172523/58013) help?

Comment: What do you mean by " momentum operator in the differential form". The standard form is: " -I hbar d/dx "