# Is there an easy way to transform unit vectors from spherical to Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-transformation

Is there a built-in function on Mathematica that will transform unit vectors from one coordinate system to another?  I have a vector expressed in spherical coordinates, and I would like to find the Cartesian components of the vector, but still express those Cartesian components using $(r,\theta,\phi)$.  The transformation I am trying to generate is listed below:

$$\hat{x}=\sin\theta\cos\phi\,\hat{r}+\cos\theta\cos\phi\,\hat{\theta}-\sin\phi\,\hat{\phi}$$
$$\hat{y}=\sin\theta\sin\phi\,\hat{r}+\cos\theta\sin\phi\,\hat{\theta}+\cos\phi\,\hat{\phi}$$
$$\hat{z}=\cos\theta\,\hat{r}-\sin\theta\,\hat{\theta}$$

The above uses the physics convention where $\theta$ is the polar angle.  So basically I would like Mathematica to automatically generate a matrix which looks like this:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\sin\theta\cos\phi&\cos\theta\cos\phi&-\sin\phi\\
\sin\theta\sin\phi&\cos\theta\sin\phi&\cos\phi\\
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta&0\\
\end{array}\right)$$

If I act this matrix on my vector (expressed in spherical coordinates) I will get what I want.  Of course I could just type this matrix in myself, but that is not very elegant...  The JacobianMatrix command is close, but not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: I would suggest opening up the Wolfram Documentation and search for "Changing Coordinate Systems" for functions and tutorials.

Comment: The answer to this question is part of the answer to the following: [How to change coordinates of a differential operator?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14361/how-to-change-coordinates-of-a-differential-operator), so I think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CoordinateTransformData[
    "Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
    "OrthonormalBasisRotation",
    {1, θ, φ}
] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!  Your solution is close, but not quite right -- the third column is not quite right.

Comment: I set `r = 1` just to conform to your example. You can just use `r`.

Comment: Sorry. Now the third column is right.

Comment: Taiki,Thank you very much.  This works great.  I can even put {r,\[Theta],\[CurlyPhi]} in there and it works. -Charlie